# Module and class with same name

Tags: f#, f#-3.1

This is allowed:

```
type Test = class end

[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Test = begin end
```

But this not:

```
[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Test = begin end

type Test = class end
```

Why?

In the second case, the error is: Duplicate definition of type or module 'Test'.

I'd love to be able to define some public `[<Literal>]` constants that are required for a type and important for users of the type inside a module with the same name.

Comment: I don't see anything in the spec about a required order, so my guess is it's a bug.

Comment: would something like "module Test_Literals", and then "open Test_Literals" prior to type Test do the trick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can open the type declaration, close it and re open later, something like this:

```
type Test = class end

[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Test =
    [<Literal>]
    let myLiteral = "myLiteral"

type Test with
    static member test = ()
```

I use this trick all the time ;)

Comment: That's a neat trick. Fixing a duplicate definition error by introducing another duplicate definition... well done, sir! But I guess it only works with type extensions? Nevertheless, this is totally usable in my case...

Comment: @NikontheThird it looks like a type extension but it is not. As long as it is in the same file the F# compiler puts everything together.

Comment: @Gustavo thanks for the nice trick, however it doesn't work when "Test" is a record type..which I do find needed occasionally.